# GitHub-Actions: Trigger on creation of Draft of GitHub-Release

Tags: github-api, github-actions

To simplify the release of a new version, I want to use GitHub-Actions to build my project. This should be triggered by creating a release-draft.

Basically, the workflow should be as follows:

When a new release should be created, a draft is created (manually), containing the proper `tag`, `name` and `body`. When the draft is saved, the action should take over and build the project in its current state, then add the built file to the release draft and finally publish it.

I don't want it to trigger when the draft is published, as it is already available then, even before the action has finished building the real file that should be released.

I tried using all triggers of `release` with

```yaml
on: # When to trigger this action
  release: # trigger on all release-events
  workflow_dispatch: # allow manual triggering
```

However, that doesn't seem to trigger when the draft is saved, only when it's being published.

Is there any way to trigger this workflow without publishing the release, but only by creating a *draft*?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release) say specifically that `release` _"is not triggered for draft releases"_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's why I'm asking: Is there any other way to trigger it when creating a draft release?

Comment: You may find [this article about release-drafter](https://johanneskonings.dev/github/2021/02/28/github_automatic_releases_and-changelog/) interesting.

Comment: Any updates on this? I will say you can detect it with an app for sure.

Comment: Related GitHub feedback thread: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/7118